# ReadMe file does not show its contents when included in set up project VS2005?

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2005

I have included a readMe file in my set up project and have associated a *.rtf file with it.
Steps I followed are--

> 1) create a *.rtf file and include it
>   in "Application Folder" of "File
>   System" by right clicking on set up
>   project.                            2)
>   Later add a ReadMe dialog in "User
>   INterface".                   3) Than
>   include this *.rtf file to it.
>   4) "Sunken" property is true.

But the contents of my *.rtf file are not getting reflected when I actually try to install my installer package. I am just getting a blank readMe file while installing the package.

Can Anyone kindly let me know the fix for this.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some googling around I found [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/34fb2fe7-7964-4249-b218-97315e56f858). It seems that if you make your rtf file with Word the file will be unreadable to the setup project. If you make it with Wordpad, no problem at all. I just tested it in vs 2005 and it works.

Comment: Why does MS Word add so much garbage to its documents in general anyway?